# svn repository moved temporarily

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket

I used bitbucket many times with no problems,today trying to checkout a project but I got the following message [image]

I tried different machines but got the same errors,Can anyone please help me to fix this problem

Comment: Can you clarify what actions you have taken, are you trying to clone a git repo with svn?

Comment: @joran - it's OK for Github: they provide SVN-backend to Git-repos

Comment: URL of git-repo in question? Otherwise ask Github's techsuppost

Comment: @LazyBadger, yes, but does Bitbucket provide svn support?